# Rest API Authentication with Autohotkey

Tags: rest, api, autohotkey

i want to POST a string with Autohotkey to a Rest API.

On another question i found something like this:

```
URL := "http://localhost:8000/createPlayer"
HttpObj := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
HttpObj.Open("POST", URL, 0)
HttpObj.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
json_str := ({"name": "Any Name"})
Body = json_str
HttpObj.Send(Body)
MsgBox, %Body%
Result := HttpObj.ResponseText
Status := HttpObj.Status
msgbox % "status: " status "`n`nresult: " result
```

so here is my Question: where do i put the authentication-information?
I read, that i have tho give the string username:password coded as Base64 to the API, but where? Thank u very much.

The Example in the documentation is(with curl):

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-d'{"type":"page","title":"new page",
"ancestors":[{"id":456}], "space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":
{"value":
"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}'
http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```

my json_string is:

```
{"type":"page","title":"new page","ancestors":[{"id":13533694}, "space":{"key":"SPIELWIESE"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don´t post in German. Stick to English. Please also proofread your questions and have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can send username/password in base64 encoded form as below:

```
HttpObj.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic [base64 encoded password here]' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! now there is no Error like "Authentication failed, but
    {"statusCode":500,"message":"org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.restapi.filters.LimitingRequestFilter$1@5b2da977; line: 1, column: 73]"}

Comment: @Folllast .. ':' colon is json key, value separator, since its part of your JSON request so its throwing error. Have you quoted your username:password encoded string. Can you show what you are sending as authentication? You can place the dummy values of username/password.